# Edit disabled status of bootstrap switch

Tags: css, input, frontend, switch-statement, bootstrap-5

Anybody knows how to style the bootstrap switch button when it's disabled? I managed to style it for enabled status but for disabled it still gets dark as a bootstrap default effect. I'd like to have it the same appearance for disabled than for enabled.

In addition, how could I check if it's enabled or disabled and make the words "annually" or "monthly" bold depending on that? Thanks!

```css
.form-check.form-switch .form-check-input {
  box-shadow: none; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  height: 20px; 
  width: 40px; 
  background-color: #5382FB; 
}

.form-check-input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + .form-check-label::before {
    background-color: #5382FB;
    border-color: #5382FB;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="monthly me-3">Monthly</div>
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
    </div>
    <div class="annually ms-3">Annually</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted it out with jQuery. I was mistaken with the ids as well:

```js
// PLANS SWITCH BUTTONS

$("#switch-1").on('change', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#price-1').html('499€')
    $('#monthly-1').css({'font-weight':'400', 'text-decoration':'none'})
    $('#annually-1').css({'font-weight':'700', 'text-decoration':'underline'})
  }
  else {
    $('#price-1').html('599€')
    $('#monthly-1').css({'font-weight':'700', 'text-decoration':'underline'})
    $('#annually-1').css({'font-weight':'400', 'text-decoration':'none'})
  }
});
```

```css
.form-check.form-switch .form-check-input {
  box-shadow: none; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  height: 20px; 
  width: 40px; 
  background-color: #5382FB; 
}

.form-check-input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + .form-check-label::before {
    background-color: #5382FB;
    border-color: #5382FB;
    opacity: 1;
} 

.annually {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-block m-auto">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><span id="price-1">499€</span></div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><span class="mb-2">/ month</span></div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div id="monthly-1" class="monthly text-end">Monthly</div>
        <div class="form-check form-switch mx-2 p-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input class="form-check-input m-auto" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="switch-1" checked>
        </div>
        <div id="annually-1" class="annually">Annually</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Disabled* is the wrong word here. It is *checked* or *unchecked* and to make the words bold you need JS and listen for the `change` event of the button.

**Example:**

```js
document.getElementById('switch').addEventListener('change', () => {
  const switchBtn = document.getElementById('switch');
  const monthly = document.getElementById('monthly');
  const annually = document.getElementById('annually');
  if (switchBtn.checked) {
    annually.classList.toggle('fw-bold');
    monthly.classList.toggle('fw-bold');
  } else {
    annually.classList.toggle('fw-bold');
    monthly.classList.toggle('fw-bold');
  }
});
```

```css
.form-check.form-switch .form-check-input {
  box-shadow: none; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  height: 20px; 
  width: 40px; 
  background-color: #5382FB; 
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='%23fff'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div id="monthly" class="me-3 fw-bold">Monthly</div>
    <div class="form-check form-switch" id="switch">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
    </div>
    <div id="annually" class="ms-3">Annually</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! anybody can explain how to do it with jQuery and for two occurrences of the whole html block? I'm trying to figure it out but with no success for now...

Comment: I realised this is not working properly. I need to change the text for other <span> depending on which status is selected and I console.log this and is entering always at the else. It's just toggling the class fw-bold but always at the else part, so I can't know which one is selected.